# LINQ query reuse and deferred execution

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I was under the impression that I could create a LINQ query and then reuse it while change the parameters involved. But it seems that you cant change the source collection. Can someone give me a good explanation as to why, as I have clearly misunderstood something fundamental.

Here is some example code.

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var value = source.Where(x => x > 5);
var first = value.ToArray();

source = Enumerable.Range(11, 20);
var second = value.ToArray();
```

I was expecting first to be 6,7,8,9,10 and second to be 11 to 20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do:

```
source = Enumerable.Range(11, 20);
```

You are creating a new object. However, the `Where` query still has a reference to the old object.

Comment: Thanks jimmy and Kendall, im going to try and elaborate on the answer a bit. In the eg below the LINQ produces a WhereArrayIterator which is referenced by the value variable. This contains a ref to the source array and the predicate. So you can update the source array and this is reflected in the result. However when I changed the source variable to a new array this does not affect the reference in the WhereArrayIterator. So the ref in the WhereArrayIterator points directly to the original source array not the source variable that it was originally declared with. Which is standard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
source = Enumerable.Range(11, 20);
    var second = value.ToArray();

second = Enumerable.Range(11, 20);
    var second = value.ToArray();
```

Find a difference ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because `value = source.Where(x => x > 5)` eagerly evaluates the value of `source`, but defers the evaluation of the `x => x > 5` part. when you reassign source, the original range is still there, source is just pointing to a different range. In short, the values inside the lambda are evaluated lazily.

**Example of the deferred execution**

```
 source = Enumerable.Range(1,10).ToArray();
 value = source.Where(x => x > 5);
 var first = value.ToArray();  // 6,7,8,9,10
 source.[0] = 100;
 var second = value.ToArray(); // 100,6,7,8,9,10
```

**Example of accessing source lazily** (i would not recommend this type of code, it's an example of how accessing the `source` variable in a lambda creates a 'closure' that can defer the access to `source`

```
source = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
value = Enumerable.Range(1).SelectMany(n => source.Where(x => x > 5));
var first = value.ToArray();
source = Enumerable.Range(11,20);
var second = value.ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I think I thought the source array would behave as if it was part of the lambda and therefore get re evaluated each time. But clearly it's not as each element is passed into the lambda.