# LINQ deferred execution - why is it not considering the change from the result of Enumerable.Range?

Tags: c#, linq, enumeration

In this code, the source 'source' is again being loaded before I actually enumerate over the resulting elements. I've seen mainly examples of an Employee Class - we have a List of Employee objects and before enumerating over the result of some query an additional object is added, which does appear in the output enumeration.

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 25);

var elements = from num in source
               num < 5
               select num;

source = Enumerable.Range(0, 25);

foreach (int num in elements)
{
   Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

This doesn't include 0 in the output. Because the query is executed only once the enumeration starts, shouldn't 0 be printed? Is there anything that I've messed up?

EDIT:
I apologize but I need one more clarification. The below code snippet does print 10 and 20 - how is it different from the above scenario?

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
    numbers.Add(1);

    IEnumerable<int> query = numbers.Select(n => n * 10);
    numbers.Add(2);

    foreach (int num in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
```

Comment: And thank heavens it works that way.

Comment: Look at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565469/linq-query-reuse-and-deferred-execution)

Comment: @HansPassant: I might have misunderstood the deferred execution part then. What is the difference between the Employee objects scenario and this?

Comment: The enumeration is deferred, not the building of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This definition of `elements` captures the thing pointed at by the variable `source`:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 25);

var elements = from num in source
               num < 5
               select num;
```

When you reassign `source`, you're just changing what that variable points at.  `elements` still references the thing that `source` pointed at at the time `elements` was defined.

This has nothing to do with LINQ specifically.  If were to write code like this:

```
var address = "123 Cherry Lane";
var contact = new Contact(address);
address = "junk";
```

The contact would still have the address `"123 Cherry Lane"`.

Comment: I edited the question to include one more piece of code which does show the change to the list, am trying to understand how is this different compared to the original?

Comment: @Kodathon The difference in your new example is that the variable `numbers` isn't reassigned.  The value `numbers` points to is modified.